# Keycloak admin-cli throwing - HTTP error - 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, keycloak

I am trying to update realm from the admin-cli but end with 415 unsupported Media type.

FYI i did not make any single change in **demorealm.json** file.

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get realms/CRUE_Realm > demorealm.json
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/CRUE_Realm > demorealm.json
```

> ```
> HTTP error - 415 Unsupported Media Type
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/CRUE_Realm -f demorealm.json
```

See also:
[Keycloak Documentation19.5. Basic operations and resource URIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#basic-operations-and-resource-uris)

> The create and update commands send a JSON body to the server by default. You can use -f FILENAME to read a premade document from a file.